# Regex Help Wanted With Capture Groups

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to extract some words from a string. The two cases look like this:

```
Case 1: "Group X - Ford Mondeo or similar"
Case 2: "Group X - Ford Mondeo"
```

I would like a single .NET regex that captures "Ford Mondeo" in both cases.
The best I have so far is:

```
^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>.+)(?: or similar)$
```

which returns:
Case 1: "Ford Mondeo"
Case 2: ""
I have tried this:

```
^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>.+)(?: or similar)?$
```

which returns:

```
Case 1: ""
Case 2: "Ford Mondeo"
```

I was trying to say zero or one occurrences of " or similar".
I may need an expression that says "if endswith "or similar" do this else this.
I've been using Expresso for a good while now and just cant put my finger on what I need. 
Can you help?

Comment: What does ?: do at the start of the second capture group?

Comment: It makes it not a capture group.  It allows the ? after it to apply to everything in it, but it doesn't get stored as a capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on whether or not you want to accept any whitespace characters:

```
/^Group\s[A-Z]\s-\s(?<VehicleModel>.+?)(?:\sor\ssimilar)?$/
```

Will capture the text with whitespace characters including tabs, and

```
/^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>.+?)(?: or similar)?$/
```

Will capture only if the text uses spaces. Like others said the key is in the `.+?` which makes the capturing group non-greedy.  Without it the first group will swallow the or similar.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.+` in the VehicleGroup captures too much. Append a question mark to make it [non-greedy](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/regex.html#SECTION000730000000000000000): `.+?`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>.+?)(?: or similar)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>.+?)(?:or similar)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dot-plus:

```
^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>)(?: or similar)?$
```

Or maybe try this:

```
^Group [A-Z] - (?<VehicleModel>.+?)(?: or similar)?$
```

I'm not familiar with this .net `?<xyz>` syntax, maybe it requires the dot-plus? In that case, `.+?` makes it non-greedy, so that the `.+` won't eat up the " or similar".